# Topology of algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have an algebraic variety given by a polynomial $1+x(1+y)^2$ over $\mathbb C$. Is there any reasonable way to see how topologically the algebraic variety defined by this polynomial looks like?

Comment: In your case it's easy to see that your curve is isomorphic to $\Bbb C^*$

Comment: Your curve is $\{ (\frac{-1}{z^2}, z-1), z \in \Bbb{C}^*\}$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^*$. To *see* it, look first at $\{ (\frac{1}{z}, z), z \in \Bbb{C}^*\}$ then apply $(u,v) \to (-u^2,v-1)$

Answer (score 0):

The open sets of that variety are the variety itself take away finite number of (algebraic) curves and points. Is this what you mean by "topologically see"?